# How to share C# property code between multiple subclasses of a class, but not all?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, properties, composition

**UPDATE** When asked why doesn't A just inherit from D instead, I probably should have stated, there will be other classes inheriting from A also. Assume that all of these subclasses have some shared functionality from A.

I have an interesting situation that I think requires some compositional approach. What I have at the moment however, is some inheritance resulting in a base class going on it's way to becoming a god class.

```
  public abstract class A
  {
      protected SameProperty {get; set;}
      protected SharedMethod();
  }

    public class B : A
    {
         //Uses SameProperty with some of its own variables
        //SharedMethod used.
    }

    public class C : A
    {
         //Also uses SameProperty with some of ITS own variables
         //SharedMethod used.
    }

    public class D : A
    {
        //Does not use SameProperty. Will never use it and there will be many other classes just like this.
        //SharedMethod used.
    }

    public class E : A
    {
        //Does not use SameProperty either.
        //SharedMethod used.
    }
```

In the example above, B and C use this property getter and setter code that would otherwise be duplicated in the subclasses themselves. So I use A to share the code between them. But what about D and all the other objects that inherit from A that will never need the property?

I have tried making an interface with SameProperty and adding it to classes B and C. This then lead me to wonder how this helps as I will still end up implementing the property code twice.

I have also tried making a static class that shares the property as a static one but that doesn't allow me to pass in the variables needed from classes B and C into the static code.

I don't think I can use methods in place of properties (what is this, Java?). So how do I do this with just properties?

Thanks,
Chucky.

UPDATE 2 I have added a concrete implementation of the problem property, which is needed in some of the subclasses but not all. For those curious, this is code in a Xamarin-iOS ViewController.

I understand what some users are suggesting about an intermediate sub-class of A that B and C both inherit from (let's say, F?).

But then, supposing subclasses D and E which inherit from A have their own intermediate class, G. But then also need the SameProperty from F. How would I do this with all these levels of inheritance? Surely composition of SameProperty into other classes is the only way? But how?

```
bool _bannerDisabled;
public bool BannerDisabled
{
    get
    {
        return _bannerDisabled;
    }
    set
    {
        if (BaseDisabledBanner != null && BaseDisabledBannerHeightConstraint != null)
        {
            _bannerDisabled = value;
            BaseDisabledBannerHeightConstraint.Constant = _bannerDisabled ? _viewHeight : 0;
            BaseDisabledBanner.Hidden = !_bannerDisabled;
            View.LayoutIfNeeded();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what any of this code is actually trying to do, we couldn't possibly comment on whether the architecture is appropriate or what a better option would be.

Comment: Why isn't D your base class and have A inherit off of it?

Comment: `D` has no business calling itself a subclass of `A`, if it has a *problem* with inheriting anything from `A`.

Comment: Technically the only way to do this is to add another class in between `A` and the others. Have it derive from `A`. Move the property `SomeProperty` to that class, have `A` and `B` derive from it and `D` derive from `A`.

Comment: Ed nailed it, design issue, re-think it.

Comment: D definitely has to subclass A, to use SharedMethod, the same way the rest do. Question updated.

Comment: If your classes need to use stuff in A rather than override then it might make more sense if your design used composition instead of inheritance, but it's hard to tell simply based on the vagueness of the example given.

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to keep the code short for readability. I will try and expand on this

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along these lines would do the trick:

```
public abstract class A0
{
    //has common code that should be implemented by all
}
public abstract class B0 : A0
{
    protected SameProperty {get; set;}
}
public class B : B0
{
     //Uses SameProperty with some of its own variables
}
public class C : B0
{
     //Also uses SameProperty with some of ITS own variables
}
public class D : A0
{
    //Does not use SameProperty. Will never use it and there will be many other classes just like this.
}
```